# Как сделать редирект с одного раздела на другой?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Есть каталог по пути

```
сайт/catalog/раздел/подраздел/элемент/
```

(вложенность может быть разная), суть вопроса, как при смене  `/catalog/` допустим на `/cat/`, сохранить рабочие ссылки, что идут как вложенности

```
/раздел/подраздел/элемент/
```

Т.Е. мы начинаем переход по ссылке

```
сайт/catalog/раздел/подраздел/элемент/
```

а нас перекидывает сразу на

```
сайт/cat/раздел/подраздел/элемент/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `catalog` находится сразу после адреса сайта, то можно сделать так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.+)$ /cat/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Если же `catalog` может находиться в любом месте пути, правило должно быть таким:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)*catalog/(.+)$ $1cat/$2 [L,R=301]
```